# Is there a true cross browser solution for shoutcast streams?

Tags: php, html, streaming, shoutcast

Shoutcast stream is giving me a serious headache.

I tried:

1. JWplayer
2. Jplayer
3. Html5 Audio

None of these are true cross-platform-browser solutions. THey can't even play all shoutcast streams!

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Maybe I can pass stream through some php library?

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody is answering, I ransacked web today and found soundmanager2 - which at least in my tests works fine both on desktop and mobile browsers.

I tested on Android, IOS, on desktop side chrome,firefox,safari and all shoutcast channels seem to work fine.

So here you go :)

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

```
soundManager.setup({
                url: 'soundManager2/swf',
                debugMode: false,
                // optional: use 100% HTML5 mode where available
                // preferFlash: false,
                onready: function() {
                  var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
                    id: 'shoutCast',
                    url: valueSelected+';',
                    type: 'audio/mp3'
                  });
                  mySound.play();
                },
                ontimeout: function() {
                  // Hrmm, SM2 could not start. Missing SWF? Flash blocked? Show an error, etc.?
                }
              });
```

valueSelected = `http://198.27.79.224:9770/`

Comment: How did this go? Any chance you can provide any information on how you got ShoutCast to work with SoundManager? Any help would be great.